# implement bezel border style for the edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to implement this border style in Android for the edit text. This is common to iOS. I think that styles and themes should suffice, however, I am not sure how to implement this bezel property. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes! you said it right Styles and themes are the way to do it. her is how google has styled the stock textView. [styles.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD) , [themes.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=6b3d7407d1c895a3c297e60d5beac98e2d34c271;hb=HEAD)

you can override them by creating you styles.xml in your project and apply them in the layout xml. [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

**EDIT**
There is something called shapes in android. [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

here is an example. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276346/help-in-using-shape-drawable-as-my-background-xml/1280337#1280337)

you can make an xml for all states like **pressed**, **normal** ... and assign as background. this can be done using **selector**. [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

or you can even use different **images** as **background** and using **selector** you can give the user a little intuitiveness.

Comment: Thanks Sam, could you know how I could implement the Bezel style using xml styles and themes??